# No module named 'tensorflow' when running train.py in conda environment

Tags: tensorflow, conda, object-detection

I try to run the train.py file to train my object detector, but I get a  `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'` error. I'm running this in my conda environment, and I can import and use tensorflow in that environment just fine. Anyone know why this happens? Thanks

```
(fastai-audio) C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\TensorFlow\workspace\classification>train.py --logtostderr --train_dir=training/ --pipeline_config_path=training/pipeline.config
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Andrew\Documents\TensorFlow\workspace\classification\train.py", line 47, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow
```

Comment: Are you using a python shebang inside the train.py code?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't figure out how to run it, so I just decided to create a jupyter notebook to run the cell in the fastai-audio kernel and it worked.